# The integral that $\int_{0}^{\pi/2} \frac{x\sin x+2-2 \cos x}{2\sin x+x\cos x+x}\,\mathrm dx=\ln 2$

Tags: integration

While manipulating with some integrals, this integral 
$$\int_{0}^{\pi/2} \frac{x\sin x+2-2 \cos x}{2\sin x+x\cos x+x}\,\mathrm dx=\ln 2$$ turned out to be doable.
So the question is: How to show it by hand?

Answer (score 5):

Hint: Using half-angle formulas, we get $$\frac{x\sin x+2-2 \cos x}{2\sin x+x\cos x+x}=\tan(x/2)\left(\frac{x\cos (x/2)+2 \sin (x/2)}{2\sin (x/2)+x\cos (x/2)}\right)=\tan(x/2),$$ which can be evaluated easily.

Answer (score 3):

Notice the law of equal proportions  that $$\frac{\sin x}{1+\cos x}=\frac{1-\cos x}{\sin x}=\frac{x\sin x}{x(1+\cos x)}=\frac{2(1-\cos x)}{2\sin x}
=\frac{x\sin x+2-2\cos x}{x+x\cos x+2\sin x.}$$
Hence $$\int_{0}^{\pi/2} \frac{x\sin x+2-2 \cos x}{2\sin x+x\cos x+x}dx=\int_{0}^{\pi/2} \frac{1-\cos x}{\sin x}dx=\int_{0}^{\pi/2}(\csc x-\cot x) dx=-2 \ln\cos(x/2))|_{0}^{\pi/2}=\ln 2.$$